# Browser access to Google-Account-Protected related Webpages

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to access related web pages hosted on Google storage, linked by relative links, with a browser via https://storage.cloud.google.com/yourbucket/yourwebpage.html ? 
Or what are the best workarounds?

Comment: Have you tried anything? People are generally more likely to help out if they have seen that you put some effort into it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by "access related web pages"?

Comment: Accessing protected html file with https://storage.cloud.google.com/yourbucket/yourwebpage.html gives a redirection to a served page at xxxxgoogleusercontent.commondatastorage.googleapis.com. So relative links in the page are also directed to this base url and return an "Invalid object URL requested" error.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `<base>` tag to your html files:

```
<head>
<base href="http://storage.googleapis.com/pub/" target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
  <a href="gsutil.tar.gz">Download gsutil</a>
</body>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp